# Django-Haystack + Whoosh - Are misspelling suggestions possible?

Tags: python, django, full-text-search, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm using Whoosh and Django-Haystack. I would like to make use of query suggestions for when users mistype words.

> e.g. Maybe you meant "unicorn"

---

Is it necessary to use another search engine? Or can I successfully achieve this with Whoosh?

Answer (score 4):

Haystack [lets you enable spelling suggestions](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/settings.html#haystack-include-spelling), and that does work with Whoosh.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Whoosh, but comparing [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) and [rolling your own](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=edit+distance+python) wouldn't be too complex, if necessary.